# How to parse a multi sheet csv into html table using php

Tags: php

I have a csv file which contains 2 sheets inside. I am trying to execute the csv file and convert it into a html table using php. but it is taking and displaying table of just one sheet. I am unable to find the other sheet's information.

For this I am using the following code,

```
 <?php
echo "<table border='1' align='center' width='70%'>\n\n";
$f = fopen("../uploads/docs/test.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table><br>";



echo "<table border='1' align='center' width='70%'>\n\n";
$f = fopen("../uploads/docs/testing.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table>";
?>
```

Please help me by which i can parse csv having multiple sheets in it to a html table

Comment: CSV files don't have 'sheets'.  How can you tell the difference between one sheet and the next?

Comment: You have to export each sheet of the multi-sheet Excel document separately into CSV files and process them all.

Comment: Ok so i have to separate each sheet to individual excel document. Is it possible, If I am adding two different tables in my single spreadsheet, how can i generate two different tables from that one spread sheet ?

Comment: Ok Now I have a SpreadSheet which contains two different tables with 2-row space. How can I generate two different tables from that single spreadsheet and show it as a html table using php (any coding help will be better). I don't want to use database. I want to do it in a static way. Upload -> Auto-generate table. That's all. Please help me with codes